# Kibana says "Kibana server is not ready yet." and "elasticsearch-reset-password" returns an error

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to Elasticsearch/Kibana and am trying to set up a basic installation via Docker. I've backed myself into a corner, and I need help finding my way out.

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`.

```
services:

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.4.0
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.4.0
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticssearch:9200
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
```

I run `docker compose up .` and the logs look mostly good. However, when I try to connect to http://localhost:5601/, I see a message "Kibana server is not ready yet." that never goes away.

The end of the Elasticsearch log looks like this.

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-26T15:26:25.616Z", "log.level":"ERROR", "message":"exception during geoip databases update", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[1de6b5b3d4cb][generic][T#4]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"vGjmfQNWTRS2sEeG0AiwuQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"3CcC2gJmRk2tQZOQTwU9HA","elasticsearch.node.name":"1de6b5b3d4cb","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException","error.message":"not all primary shards of [.geoip_databases] index are active","error.stack_trace":"org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: not all primary shards of [.geoip_databases] index are active\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.4.0/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.updateDatabases(GeoIpDownloader.java:134)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.4.0/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.runDownloader(GeoIpDownloader.java:274)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.4.0/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:102)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.4.0/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:48)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.4.0/org.elasticsearch.persistent.NodePersistentTasksExecutor$1.doRun(NodePersistentTasksExecutor.java:42)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.4.0/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:769)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.4.0/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\n"}
2022-08-26T15:26:26.005783998Z {"@timestamp":"2022-08-26T15:26:26.002Z", "log.level": "INFO",  "current.health":"GREEN","message":"Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.geoip_databases][0]]]).","previous.health":"RED","reason":"shards started [[.geoip_databases][0]]" , "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[1de6b5b3d4cb][masterService#updateTask][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.AllocationService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"vGjmfQNWTRS2sEeG0AiwuQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"3CcC2gJmRk2tQZOQTwU9HA","elasticsearch.node.name":"1de6b5b3d4cb","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
2022-08-26T15:26:26.264786433Z {"@timestamp":"2022-08-26T15:26:26.264Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-Country.mmdb]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[1de6b5b3d4cb][generic][T#2]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.DatabaseNodeService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"vGjmfQNWTRS2sEeG0AiwuQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"3CcC2gJmRk2tQZOQTwU9HA","elasticsearch.node.name":"1de6b5b3d4cb","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
2022-08-26T15:26:26.304814423Z {"@timestamp":"2022-08-26T15:26:26.304Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[1de6b5b3d4cb][generic][T#3]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.DatabaseNodeService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"vGjmfQNWTRS2sEeG0AiwuQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"3CcC2gJmRk2tQZOQTwU9HA","elasticsearch.node.name":"1de6b5b3d4cb","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
2022-08-26T15:26:27.017126446Z {"@timestamp":"2022-08-26T15:26:27.016Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-City.mmdb]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[1de6b5b3d4cb][generic][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.DatabaseNodeService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"vGjmfQNWTRS2sEeG0AiwuQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"3CcC2gJmRk2tQZOQTwU9HA","elasticsearch.node.name":"1de6b5b3d4cb","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
```

I'm not sure if that ERROR about "geoip databases" is a problem. It does look like cluster health is "GREEN".

The end of the Kibana logs looks like this.

```
[2022-08-26T15:26:25.032+00:00][INFO ][plugins.ruleRegistry] Installing common resources shared between all indices
2022-08-26T15:26:25.091816903Z [2022-08-26T15:26:25.091+00:00][INFO ][plugins.cloudSecurityPosture] Registered task successfully [Task: cloud_security_posture-stats_task]
2022-08-26T15:26:26.081102019Z [2022-08-26T15:26:26.080+00:00][INFO ][plugins.screenshotting.config] Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection, and is supported for Linux Ubuntu 20.04 OS. Automatically enabling Chromium sandbox.
2022-08-26T15:26:26.155818080Z [2022-08-26T15:26:26.155+00:00][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND elasticssearch
2022-08-26T15:26:26.982333104Z [2022-08-26T15:26:26.981+00:00][INFO ][plugins.screenshotting.chromium] Browser executable: /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/screenshotting/chromium/headless_shell-linux_x64/headless_shell
```

That "Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes." ERROR looks more like it could be a problem, but I'm not sure what to do about it. [One online question](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-cannot-connect-to-es-cluster-unable-to-retrieve-version-information-from-elasticsearch-nodes/278185) that sounds similar comes down to the difference between ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS and ELASTICSEARCH_URL for an earlier version of Elastic that doesn't seem relevant here.

Poking around online also turns up situations in which the "Kibana server is not ready yet." error is a problem with the security setup. The [whole security setup part](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-stack-security.html) is a bit confusing to me, but it seems like one thing that might have happened is that I failed to setup passwords correctly. I'm trying to start over, so I shelled into the Elasticsearch instance and ran `elasticsearch-reset-password --username elastic`. I saw the following error.

```
elasticsearch@1de6b5b3d4cb:~$ elasticsearch-reset-password --username elastic
15:24:34.593 [main] WARN  org.elasticsearch.common.ssl.DiagnosticTrustManager - failed to establish trust with server at [172.18.0.2]; the server provided a certificate with subject name [CN=1de6b5b3d4cb], fingerprint [cc4a98abd8b44925c631d7e4b05f048317c8e02b], no keyUsage and extendedKeyUsage [serverAuth]; the session uses cipher suite [TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384] and protocol [TLSv1.3]; the certificate has subject alternative names [IP:172.18.0.3,DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1,DNS:1de6b5b3d4cb]; the certificate is issued by [CN=Elasticsearch security auto-configuration HTTP CA]; the certificate is signed by (subject [CN=Elasticsearch security auto-configuration HTTP CA] fingerprint [ba8730cc6481e4847e4a14eff4f774ca1c96ad0b] {trusted issuer}) which is self-issued; the [CN=Elasticsearch security auto-configuration HTTP CA] certificate is trusted in this ssl context ([xpack.security.http.ssl (with trust configuration: Composite-Trust{JDK-trusted-certs,StoreTrustConfig{path=certs/http.p12, password=<non-empty>, type=PKCS12, algorithm=PKIX}})])
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 172.18.0.2 found
```

Those are all the problems I have encountered. I don't know what they mean or which are significant, and Googling doesn't turn up any clear next steps. Any suggestions as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. Stupid mistake. I misspelled elasticsearch in the line.

```
ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticssearch:9200
```

"ss" instead of "s". Easy to overlook. The error message in the Kibana logs was telling me what the problem was. I just didn't know how to interpret it.

Even though this was just a typo I'm going to leave this question up in case someone makes the same mistake and gets confused in the same way.